# how to remove the background gray make it 50x50 in html

Tags: html, css

Hi in the below code how to remove the background gray color and my image background was showing 50x50.
expected output:

circle with image with black border image should be center.if image size 128x128px means i want to change to 50x50 automatically.

**html**

```
<div class="specilites">
    <img src="img/Ambulance-128 (3).png"/>
&nbsp;
</div>
```

**css**

```
    .specilites img{
    background: url(http://placehold.it/50x50);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius:50px;
    -moz-border-radius:50px;
    border-radius:50px;
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
     border: 1px solid #008080;
}
```

Comment: what is the size of the image? and would it change?

Comment: Do you want something like this? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/L136gcaz/1/)

Comment: @Mr_Green only i want circle with border and there is no backgroung color image size should be 50x50 suppose if i add next image means it should change to  50x50

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your explanation. Please take time to rephrase your question.

Comment: @Mr_Green I got solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background of img tag by using `background-color` property of `<img>` tag in css and remove the background image. Here the example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwh2rzhf/).